# How can I implement a GAN network for text (review) generation?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, generative-adversarial-networks, software-evaluation

How can I implement a GAN network for text (review) generation?

Please, can someone guide me to resource (code) to help in text generation?

Answer (score 2):

As @Clement mentions, [text_gen_description](https://becominghuman.ai/generative-adversarial-networks-for-text-generation-part-1-2b886c8cab10) gives a good overview!, but the paper [seqGAN paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05473) describes the REINFORCE approach more in depth, as they are the first to do it (i believe). This is probably the approach most take now of days when going the GAN route.

Note that just basic MLE training has shown promise with openAI's GPT2. When i need a text generator, fine tuning one of the provided models is usually my goto.

Also if your looking for seq gans code base (you asked for example code) here is is: [git repo](https://github.com/LantaoYu/SeqGAN)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

For the resources, you can refer to this:
https://becominghuman.ai/generative-adversarial-networks-for-text-generation-part-1-2b886c8cab10
If you want to generate text review for specific score, you can input a noise vector and the score to the generator. You could also make a vector filled with the number of score and add noise to that vector instead.